# Python - Dictionary is showing up as a List and can't access it

Tags: python

I'm new to Python and I am currently trying to extract some weather data from an online API (https://www.worldweatheronline.com/developer/premium-api-explorer.aspx).

**I want to access the "percipMM" field on a given day.**

The code is as follows:

```
import urllib.request
import pandas as pd
import json

with urllib.request.urlopen('http://api.worldweatheronline.com/premium/v1/past-weather.ashx?key=[API_KEY_REMOVED]&q=London&format=json&extra=utcDateTime&date=2020-01-1&enddate=2020-01-3&includelocation=yes&tp=24') as response:
   WEATHER_DATA = response.read()

# convert to JSON object
JSON = json.loads(WEATHER_DATA)

# Access 24 hourly data on Day 1 - this is a list!!! Not a Dictionary. Why?
JSONDATA['data']['weather'][1]['hourly']

# Access percipitation value - error - index out of bounds here.
JSONDATA['data']['weather'][1]['hourly']['percipMM']
```

The JSON object is as follows:

```
{
    "data": {
        "request": [
            {
                "type": "City",
                "query": "London, United Kingdom"
            }
        ],
        "nearest_area": [
            {
                "areaName": [
                    {
                        "value": "London"
                    }
                ],
                "country": [
                    {
                        "value": "United Kingdom"
                    }
                ],
                "region": [
                    {
                        "value": "City of London, Greater London"
                    }
                ],
                "latitude": "51.517",
                "longitude": "-0.106"
            }
        ],
        "weather": [
            {
                "date": "2020-01-01",
                "astronomy": [
                    {
                        "sunrise": "08:06 AM",
                        "sunset": "04:01 PM",
                        "moonrise": "11:37 AM",
                        "moonset": "10:44 PM",
                        "moon_phase": "Waxing Crescent",
                        "moon_illumination": "37"
                    }
                ],
                "maxtempC": "7",
                "maxtempF": "45",
                "mintempC": "3",
                "mintempF": "37",
                "avgtempC": "6",
                "avgtempF": "43",
                "totalSnow_cm": "0.0",
                "sunHour": "8.0",
                "uvIndex": "1",
                "hourly": [
                    {
                        "time": "24",
                        "tempC": "7",
                        "tempF": "45",
                        "windspeedMiles": "3",
                        "windspeedKmph": "6",
                        "winddirDegree": "165",
                        "winddir16Point": "SSE",
                        "weatherCode": "143",
                        "weatherIconUrl": [
                            {
                                "value": "http://cdn.worldweatheronline.net/images/wsymbols01_png_64/wsymbol_0006_mist.png"
                            }
                        ],
                        "weatherDesc": [
                            {
                                "value": "Mist"
                            }
                        ],
                        "precipMM": "0.0",
                        "precipInches": "0.0",
                        "humidity": "83",
                        "visibility": "8",
                        "visibilityMiles": "4",
                        "pressure": "1029",
                        "pressureInches": "31",
                        "cloudcover": "30",
                        "HeatIndexC": "6",
                        "HeatIndexF": "43",
                        "DewPointC": "4",
                        "DewPointF": "38",
                        "WindChillC": "5",
                        "WindChillF": "41",
                        "WindGustMiles": "5",
                        "WindGustKmph": "8",
                        "FeelsLikeC": "5",
                        "FeelsLikeF": "41",
                        "uvIndex": "1"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "date": "2020-01-02",
                "astronomy": [
                    {
                        "sunrise": "08:06 AM",
                        "sunset": "04:03 PM",
                        "moonrise": "11:54 AM",
                        "moonset": "11:51 PM",
                        "moon_phase": "First Quarter",
                        "moon_illumination": "44"
                    }
                ],
                "maxtempC": "10",
                "maxtempF": "49",
                "mintempC": "4",
                "mintempF": "38",
                "avgtempC": "8",
                "avgtempF": "46",
                "totalSnow_cm": "0.0",
                "sunHour": "3.0",
                "uvIndex": "1",
                "hourly": [
                    {
                        "time": "24",
                        "tempC": "10",
                        "tempF": "49",
                        "windspeedMiles": "9",
                        "windspeedKmph": "14",
                        "winddirDegree": "207",
                        "winddir16Point": "SSW",
                        "weatherCode": "122",
                        "weatherIconUrl": [
                            {
                                "value": "http://cdn.worldweatheronline.net/images/wsymbols01_png_64/wsymbol_0004_black_low_cloud.png"
                            }
                        ],
                        "weatherDesc": [
                            {
                                "value": "Overcast"
                            }
                        ],
                        "precipMM": "0.0",
                        "precipInches": "0.0",
                        "humidity": "88",
                        "visibility": "7",
                        "visibilityMiles": "4",
                        "pressure": "1020",
                        "pressureInches": "31",
                        "cloudcover": "91",
                        "HeatIndexC": "8",
                        "HeatIndexF": "46",
                        "DewPointC": "6",
                        "DewPointF": "43",
                        "WindChillC": "5",
                        "WindChillF": "41",
                        "WindGustMiles": "14",
                        "WindGustKmph": "23",
                        "FeelsLikeC": "5",
                        "FeelsLikeF": "41",
                        "uvIndex": "1"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "date": "2020-01-03",
                "astronomy": [
                    {
                        "sunrise": "08:06 AM",
                        "sunset": "04:04 PM",
                        "moonrise": "12:10 PM",
                        "moonset": "No moonset",
                        "moon_phase": "First Quarter",
                        "moon_illumination": "51"
                    }
                ],
                "maxtempC": "10",
                "maxtempF": "51",
                "mintempC": "7",
                "mintempF": "44",
                "avgtempC": "9",
                "avgtempF": "48",
                "totalSnow_cm": "0.0",
                "sunHour": "4.9",
                "uvIndex": "1",
                "hourly": [
                    {
                        "time": "24",
                        "tempC": "10",
                        "tempF": "51",
                        "windspeedMiles": "10",
                        "windspeedKmph": "17",
                        "winddirDegree": "312",
                        "winddir16Point": "NW",
                        "weatherCode": "266",
                        "weatherIconUrl": [
                            {
                                "value": "http://cdn.worldweatheronline.net/images/wsymbols01_png_64/wsymbol_0017_cloudy_with_light_rain.png"
                            }
                        ],
                        "weatherDesc": [
                            {
                                "value": "Light drizzle"
                            }
                        ],
                        "precipMM": "7.1",
                        "precipInches": "0.3",
                        "humidity": "79",
                        "visibility": "8",
                        "visibilityMiles": "4",
                        "pressure": "1020",
                        "pressureInches": "31",
                        "cloudcover": "66",
                        "HeatIndexC": "9",
                        "HeatIndexF": "49",
                        "DewPointC": "6",
                        "DewPointF": "42",
                        "WindChillC": "7",
                        "WindChillF": "44",
                        "WindGustMiles": "15",
                        "WindGustKmph": "24",
                        "FeelsLikeC": "7",
                        "FeelsLikeF": "44",
                        "uvIndex": "1"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

In order to further restrict this, I access the 'hourly' data set. **However, this is a list (??, even though it looks like a dictionary to me) and when I go to extract my 'percipMM' value from it, I get an error that "Index out of bounds"? How am I supposed to access this data?**

Comment: "# Access 24 hourly data on Day 1 - this is a list!!! Not a Dictionary. Why?" What is the next symbol after the colon here: `"hourly": [`?

Comment: It looks like `JSONDATA['data']['weather'][0]['hourly'][0]['percipMM']` might be what you need.

Comment: Ah. My apologies. I missed that. Thank you very much. JSON looks very intimidating at first.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The value of `hourly` is a list, not a dict.

```
...

"hourly": [
                {
                   ...
                    "precipMM": "0.0",
                    "precipInches": "0.0",
                    "humidity": "83",
                    "visibility": "8",
                    "visibilityMiles": "4",

...
```

So you need to index it as well.

```
JSONDATA['data']['weather'][1]['hourly'][0]['percipMM']
```